# Unexpected behavior of SelectableText when specifying PageStorageKey on parent

Tags: flutter

My goal was to keep the scroll position of the list. I added PageStorageKey to the list. However, this caused strange behavior for SelectableText inside the list. It feels like SelectableText wants to save/receive its position too. Because of this, the text jumps around (сalls animateTo() as Scrollable).

Is there any way to tell SelectableText to be a static Text, not Scrollable?

Here is the code that reproduces the problem. You have to scroll down and then quickly up to see that SelectableText starts jumping (animating).

```dart
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          key: const PageStorageKey("key"),
          children: [
            ...List.generate(10, (index) => const SelectableText("Selectable", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
            ...List.generate(200, (index) => Text("Text")),
          ],
        ),
      );
}
```

Example: (https://i.postimg.cc/PfQMwrFg/ezgif-com-video-to-gif.gif)

[image: Example]